# Tem como conectar um app cordova diretamente ao Mysql?

Tags: android, mysql, apache-cordova

Quero fazer um sistema com servidor mysql local em um desktop, porém sem usar **PHP ou ASP**. Então o android faria a conexão direta. É possível? Obrigado.

Comment: Não, não é possivel, você pode usar algum banco de dados local, mas não o `mysql`

Comment: Rafael então não tem como criar um aplicativo android que funcione em rede interna? Tanto tempo que o android é tão usado e ninguém se propôs a fazer isso?

Comment: tem como se conectar por javascript usando ajax, mas ainda não descobri como que faz.. obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso funcionar você precisa de uma interface de comunicação entre sua aplicação e o banco de dados.

Isso se dá pelo fato de o MYSQL não resolver a questão do transporte da informação, apenas o armazenamento dela.

Para rodar localmente como você quer, de qualquer forma precisará de uma API que fará o meio de campo entre o Android e o Mysql.

Uma alternativa, porém, não tenho conhecimento para falar muito, é você armazenar o dado em algum serviço. Procure por DBaaS. Firebase é um exemplo, porém ficará remoto e não local.